# Does sexual position affect the chances of conception?

Tags: sexuality, pregnancy, human-reproduction, sperm

I have seen the claim that some sexual positions are better for getting pregnant than others. For example this article on [how to have baby-making sex](http://www.askamum.co.uk/Trying-to-conceive/Search-Results/Sex/How-to-have-baby-making-sex-continued/) claims:

> **Be a missionary**
>
> It might seem like the boring way to get intimate, but the missionary position, with all that deep penetration close to your cervix, is going to give your partner’s sperm a little extra help in their swim for the egg!
>
> **Staying behind**
>
> Doing it doggy-style is guaranteed to get your partner’s sperm close to that all-important baby-making organ – the cervix.

Do these sexual positions increase the probability of conceiving?

Comment: I'm tempted to ask you to split this into two questions: one about the missionary position and the other about doggy-style.

Comment: Most evidence here is anecdotal. There seem to be too many factors(i.e. things like how a woman's  uterus is shaped; how healthy they both are, etc). The issue is how can you control for all variables.

Comment: @Adel by having a large sample?

Comment: @kotekzot: I'd always heard that having a large sample does help increase the chance of conception... *rimshot*